# cant run simple spring boot application in intellij, says "No Docker Compose file found" when I am not using Docker

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I generated a simple spring boot application template using the official initalizr with the lombok, kafka and web plugins, then imported the resultant dir structure as "project form existing source".

The intellij docs say one just needs to hit the green arrow next to the main method or the class with the main method in it to run the spring boot app.

However, when I do this, I get:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Docker Compose file found

I do not know why its trying to treat spring boot as a docker project, and is looking for non existant docker configs in the spring boot project.

If I manually run the project outside intellij by doing:

./mvnw spring-boot:run

It works.  The problem is getting intellij to run the spring boot app.

Here is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ohds</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kafka1</name>
    <description>kafka test project 1</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Is it possible to share your project example for investigation?

Comment: Yes, code is here: https://github.com/johnvlittle/kafka1  the only difference is my local version has application.properties which is the same as application.properties.clean in the git repo which has my passwords etc. hidden

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side. Is it reproducible with new project?